# stored procedure for fetching data from multiple tables

Tags: stored-procedures

I have Stored procedure like this

```
Select k.HBarcode, m.make,t.plateno ,v.vtype ,l.locname,mdl.model,c.Colname 
from   transaction_tbl t,
       KHanger_tbl k,
       make_tbl m,
       vtype_tbl v,
       Location_tbl l,
       Model_tbl mdl,
       Color_tbl C  
 where t.tbarcode=@carid and 
       t.mkid=m.mkid and 
       v.vtid=t.vtid and 
       t.locid=l.locid and 
       mdl.mdlid=t.mdlid and 
       t.colid=c.colid and 
       t.transactID=k.transactID
```

while executing this am getting output

```
HBarcode     make     plateno    vtype   locname          model        Colname
34           BMW      44554      Normal  Fashion Avenue   520          Red
```

I have two more tables,  from transaction table I can get transactid (above ex:**t.transactID**),then I can get the corresponding
**tid** from "KHanger_tbl",then i want show uniquename for corresponding **tid** from "Terminal" table

1-KHanger_tbl

```
transactid                              HBarcode                tid
--------------------------------------- ----------------------------------
19                                      34                      7
22                                      002                     5
21                                      1                       7
23                                      200005                   6
```

2- Terminals_tbl

```
tid         UniqueName
----------- --------------------------------------------------
5           Key Room-1
6           Podium -1
7           Key Room - 2
```

### Expected output

```
 UniqueName HBarcode make plateno vtype  locname               model  Colname
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 KeyRoom-2  34       BMW  44554   Norma Fashion Avenue       520      Red
```

so how I can write stored procedure for this, if any one knows,please help me

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe ?

```
Select  term.UniqueName , 
   k.HBarcode, m.make,t.plateno ,v.vtype ,l.locname,mdl.model,c.Colname 
from transaction_tbl t,
     KHanger_tbl k,
     make_tbl m,
     vtype_tbl v,
     Location_tbl l,
     Model_tbl mdl,
     Color_tbl C  
     ,
     Terminals_tbl Term

where t.tbarcode=@carid and 
      t.mkid=m.mkid and 
      v.vtid=t.vtid and 
      t.locid=l.locid and 
      mdl.mdlid=t.mdlid and 
      t.colid=c.colid and 
      t.transactID=k.transactID 
      and
      term.tid = t.transactID
```